# How to export a table of functions

Tags: functions, export

Consider a table having rows `{a, b, f[a,b,t]}`, where a,b are parameters while f is a function of t (being the numeric solution of some differential equation). Is it possible to export such a table in the external file?

Comment: Have you tried `Export`?

Comment: @JohnDoty : in which format should I export the function f? I would not like to export is as a table.

Comment: What are going to do with the exported table? Do you expect it to be readable by some other app? It us not likely that any other app will be able to use the Wolfram Language interpolation functions you want to export.

Comment: @m_goldberg : I would like to use it in new session of the Mathematica.

Comment: In that case, you don't need `Export`. Write it out with `Put` and read it in with `Get`.

Comment: @m_goldberg : could you please tell me which file format should I use with Put? .m?

Comment: Either .m or .wl should work.

Comment: Strongly urge you to read this [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ReadingAndWritingWolframSystemFiles.html). In particular look at `Save`

Comment: `.m` is not a format, it's a file name extension. It's just part of the name. It can be anything, but it is customary to use `.m` or `.wl` so that later you can tell what format the file contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to export it?

- If you want to read the data back to Mathematica later, you can [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) to the MX format (fast but less compatible between versions) or the WDX format (more compatible).
- If you want to transfer the data to another system, use whatever format that system can read. For complex data that can't easily be represented as a simple table, JSON is often convenient.

  Look up the RawJSON export format in Mathematica's documentation. It uses `Association`s instead of `Rule`s, which is often more convenient.